# How to pass a polymorphic object as a derived one?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance

to keep things simple I have two classes: `ActionTaken` and `MovementTaken`. `MovementTaken` is a derived class from `ActionTaken`. I have a `Queue` full of actions, and each action has a `char` that determines the type of action. (Every action has a correct type) I want to pass elements of the `Queue` to a function, that works specifically with a `MovementTaken` parameter, but since I'm using polymorphism the parameter is of type `ActionTaken`, but then I cannot use member variables from `MovementTaken`, but don't exist in `ActionTaken`. But if I set the function `activateMovement`'s parameter to type `MovementTaken`, I believe there would be an error, saying you cannot convert a base type to a derived type. Here's the code:

```
public abstract class ActionTaken : MonoBehaviour
{
    public char type;
    public Transform minionTakingAction;
}

public class MovementTaken : ActionTaken
{
    public int targetTileH;
    public int targetTileV;
    public MovementTaken(Transform _minionTakingAction, int _targetTileH, int _targetTileV)
    {
        type = 'M';
        minionTakingAction = _minionTakingAction;
        targetTileH = _targetTileH;
        targetTileV = _targetTileV;
    }
}

Queue<ActionTaken> actionTaken;
public void activateMovement(ActionTaken toActivate)
{//some code using toActivate's members targetTileH and targetTileV}
```

Comment: Are public fields really in these classes or is that just for the example?

Comment: I know I should use getters and setters instead, but this is a small project for the moment and it's easier to work on it for the time being.

Comment: Looks like an xy problem to me, the question is *why* you need to upcast everything to base class, put it in the queue and then *downcast* it again

Answer (score 1):

If you know the argument passed to the method is a `MovementTaken` instance, you can just downcast it:

```
public void activateMovement(ActionTaken toActivate)
{
    MovementTaken casted = toActivate as MovementTaken;
    // Do something with casted.targetTileH and/or caster.targetTileV
```

Comment: This seems like an anti-pattern.  Would't it be better to have the method invoked in `activateMovement` be defied on the base class, and implemented in the sub class?

Comment: Casting with ‘as‘ would probably be better here to avoid the exception if it cannot be cast to that type.

Comment: @RonBeyer yeah, good point, thanks. Old habits die hard, I guess. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: If you use `as`, make sure you check the result for null.

Comment: @JoeWhiteif you use pattern matching you can make it even easier:  `if(toActivate Is MovementTaken movement)` ...

Comment: @ParrishHusband Agreed. Why don't you make that an answer to the question? It's a great fit for what OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of `Abstract` classes is defining base implementation, or to force derived types into implementation details:

```
public abstract class ActionTaken : MonoBehaviour
{
    public char Type { get; protected set; }
    public Transform Target { get; }

    // base ctor
    protected ActionTaken(Transform target)
    {
        Type = '\0'; 
        Target = target;
    }

    // Force implementation onto sub class
    public abstract void Activate();
}

public class MovementTaken : ActionTaken
{
    public int TileH { get; set; }
    public int TileV { get; set; }

    public MovementTaken(Transform target, int tileH, int tileV)
        : base(target)
    {
        Type = 'M';
        TileH = tileH;
        TileV = tileV;
    }

    public override void Activate()
    {
        //some code using TileH and TileV
    }
}
```

Therefore your calling code would be:

```
Queue<ActionTaken> actionTaken;
public void activateMovement(ActionTaken action)
{
    action.Activate();
}
```

I'm also not sure what `Type` is being used for, but if you still need it, it might be better off as a constant defined in each class that derives from `ActionTaken` if you have more.

This can make sense if you end up filling your `Queue<ActionTaken>` with various derived movement types.  Otherwise your `ActivateMovement` method could end up being a long `switch` statement.

An interface also might be advantageous here:

```
public interface IActionTaken
{
    Transform Target { get; }

    void Activate();
}
```

Which you would then replace your queue:  `Queue<IActionTaken> Actions`

The code for invoking all of the actions in the queue could then be extremely straightforward:

```
while(Actions.Count > 0)
{
    IActionTaken current = Actions.Dequeue();
    current.Activate();
}
```